# Redirected site files for desktop downloader

Tags: php

i temporarily change place for static files on site. But this files must have access from old URL, i've create a script that make's redirect to the right place, but this files are downloading by third-part program.

The problem is that program ignoring redirect. I tryed to use permanent redirecting but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so a redirect doesn't work.

What you can do is read the file in PHP and output it directly. You can use the function readfile() to do that.

```
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: Sounds great, but i have 1,7TB of files, 1 file - 1,4 GB, new place - CDN will have better balancing that my 1 server.

Comment: Ah, it's on a different server. Can't you transfer de domain to the CDN, so it's just like it was before?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(, seems like readfile() it's only way to fix it